# android:maxLength not working on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Siduation**
I was trying to limit the amount of characters in my `EditText` using the flag `android:maxLength`.

**Code**

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/someComponent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/someComponent2"
   android:background="@null"
   android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
   android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
   android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
   android:maxLength="10"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:textStyle="normal"
   />
```

**Problem**
For some reason it doesn't seem to have any effect. I can enter as many Characters as i wish

**Question**
Can anyone explain why the EditText doesn't behave according to its flags? Are there any flags which interfere with `android:maxLength`?

**EDIT**
Problem was found. Had nothing to do with the EditText. Was related to some wrongly committed changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/someComponent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/someComponent2"
   android:background="@null"
   android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
   android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
   android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
   android:maxLength="10"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:textStyle="normal"
   android:maxEms="10"/>
```